# Invoice software to attach a PDF file to an e-mail and add text before it

Tags: macos, email, pdf, software-rec

I'm testing this 3 apps: [Billings](http://Billings%20or%20Grand%20Total%20or%20On%20the%20job), [On the job](http://stuntsoftware.com/onthejob/) and [Grand Total](http://www.grandtotal.biz/GrandTotal/) running on OS X Snow Leopard. They are invoicing applications. I need it to create recurring invoces for my clients. I tried them all and found the same problem with all of them:

When I send a recurring invoice:

1. I click 'send'
2. Then I click 'send mail'
3. The compose mail window shows up and the PDF file (the invoice) is attached (using Mail or Thunderbird)

So far so good but I'd like to adds some text ABOVE the PDF file, something like "Hello John. Find enclosed the invoice for the month of August."

This text should be plain text in the email body and not part of the PDF file generated by the application.

I have to send more than 200 recurring invoices monthly. Manually writting a text for each one is time wasting , even though if I copy and paste or use something like 'typinator'.

I already contact their support but it seems that I can't do this by any way.

Comment: I think some administrator changed the title since the name of the applications were in the title. The 3 apps are: Billings, On the job and Grand Total running on OS Leopard Snow. Mail clients: I tried with Mail and Thunderbird

Comment: I had edited the title because it wasn't too clear before, I thought you would have mentioned the apps within the body itself, sorry!

Comment: I agree with you, the title is much clear now. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is something that a batch emailer could probably accomplish for you (see software below).

Another option is to create a rule in Mail.app and attach an Applescript to it. The Applescript route would probably require some knowledge (and patience) on your part to effectively make your job easier.

- [Mailings](http://limit-point.com/products/mailings/)
- [Direct Mail](http://ethreesoftware.com/directmail/index.php)
- [RoboPostman](http://koingosw.com/products/robopostman.php)
- [MailActOn](http://www.indev.ca/MailActOn.html)

Comment: I understand that if I use (1), (2) or (3) then I don't need any other invoice app. I mean you sugest to use one of this instead of the 3 invoice apps I listed above. Is this right?

Comment: Regarding to create a Rule in Mail app: can you post any link to start learning about it? Thanks

Comment: To answer your question properly; Do you currently use any of the invoicing applications that you mentioned (if so which one), and do the invoices change month-month for your customers?

I will post back shortly regarding the Rules/Applescript method.

Comment: Collection of the Applescripts that can be implemented with Mail.app rules:

(http://andreasamann.com/MacOSX/Mail_Scripts.html)

Comment: I've added another application to the list that might help aid in your workflow.

Comment: 1) I already bought Billings, but I tried them all.  2)My invoices are the same each month (same amount).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the apps you have mentioned, but what I can say is that you can do exactly what you want using Xero, which is an online accounting web-app. It allows you to do recurring invoices, mailed automatically, with a customised email.

Comment: thanks but monthly payments for invoicing task is not in my mind right now.

Answer (score 0):

I needed exactly the same thing, and found it in a program called [Express Invoice](http://www.nchsoftware.com/invoice/index.html) from NCH, an Australian company.  It takes one click to email a pdf invoice, but it first shows a dialog where you can type a message in... however, you don't need to type a message because it will put a standard "invoice attached" message in the email body for you anyway.

Also, if you are a single business and don't need networking you can run the free version - when the trial period expires just do an uninstall and it gives you the option to downgrade to free version.  You can still buy a license later if you find you need networking.